# Can't present alertViewController on rootViewController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uialertviewcontroller

I want to show alertViewController on my rootViewController in AppDelegate when app is launched.  Here snippet of code:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "This is title", message: "This is message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
 }
```

alert is not appearing on rootViewController. Please help me.

Comment: Does `window` have a value or is it nil? Same question for `rootViewController`.

Comment: Check windowLevel and make it equal to UIWindowLevelAlert

Comment: window and rootViewController is not nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the view isn't yet loaded, if you look at console you may find log like this:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on 'swiftHere.ViewController: 0x7ff289007740' whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

You may dispatch it until rootViewController loads:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {

       let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "This is title", message: "This is message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
      self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```